# .find() does not work on certain id's

Tags: php, jquery, html, get, find

In my website the clients can update their personal data. After the update is done on the database, I want the page updates itself and show the data as it is at that time. For doing this, I do an ajax call to an external php file to update the mysql database. After that, I do a get of the client data page (location.href) and I update some div info to show up the new data.

This is the AJAX call from my JS file:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "factupdate.php",
    data: {
        datos: stringDatos, 
        token: $("#token").val(), 
        isAjax: 1
    },
    success: function (codi) {
        $.get(location.href, function (datos) {
            ($(datos)).find("#eltoken").html());
            var eltoken = $(datos).find("#eltoken");
            var result = $(datos).find("#cuenta_menu_fac");
            console.log($(eltoken).html());
            console.log($(result).html());
            $(result).find(".facturacion").hide();
            $(result).find("#fac_" + num).show();
            $(result).find(".afac").removeClass("aliselected");
            $(result).find("#menu_fac_" + num).addClass("aliselected");
            $(result).find("#acc_fac").append('<span class="goodvalid">Datos de facturación actualizados</span>');
            $("#cuenta_menu_fac").html($(result).html());
            $("#eltoken").html($(datos).find("#eltoken").html());
            $("#cargandoacc").hide();
        });
    },
    error: function (e) {
        $("#cargandoacc").hide();
        alert('Ha habido un error: ' + e);
    }
});
```

The problem is that I can see the result data but not the eltoken's, the console prints undefined.

Moreover, when I try to do a `console.log($(datos).html());` it also shows up as undefined. On the other hand, if I do a `console.log($(datos).text());` it does return the correct data of the website.

This is some of datos info:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" lang="es" xml:lang="es">
<head>
...
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
...
</head>
<body>
<!-- Some layout divs -->



<div id="cuenta_menu_fac" class="c-menu-content">
<div class="content" id="acc_fac">

<!-- Some label and input for updating data divs -->

</div>
</div>




<!-- /Some layout divs -->
<div id="eltoken">
<input type="hidden" id="token" value="2d5951d1e3b31dfb7fd2dcc172df17fd">
</div>
</body></html>
```

I do not understand what is wrong in my code. Any possible solution to this?

Comment: What is the content of `datos` thats returned in your request?

Comment: set the dataType to html

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan datos is supposed to contain the page with the whole info of the client updated. In fact, when doing `console.log($(datos).text());` is shows that info but fails when doing `.html()`.

Comment: @madalinivascu Than you for your help. Anyway, I just tried that and the same thing happens...

Comment: Could you add a sample of the content `datos` contains to the question

Comment: I think you need to append received html to a page before.
`$.get(location.href, function (datos) {
document.append(datos);
($(datos)).find("#eltoken").html());`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Just added it.

Comment: do a `console.log(typeof(datos))` and  `console.log(typeof($(datos).html())`

Comment: @madalinivascu `console.log(typeof(datos))` returns string and `console.log(typeof($(datos).html()))` returns undefined

Comment: why do you need `$(datos).html()` in the first place?

Comment: @madalinivascu I do not need it. I just need 2 div from `datos`: `#cuenta_menu_fac` and `#eltoken` which I try to acces to with `.find()` but it can only find the first one. I was only accessing to `$(datos).html()` for testing purposes.

Comment: if #eltoken is added via js you will not find it

Comment: @madalinivascu Well, that div is always there on that page. I get the data of the page again with the get. And the intention is to modify the value so `#eltoken` is there by html, not js. Is this what you meant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Datos` is not a parent for `eltoken`. Just add eg. a common `div` for it.

```
$.get(location.href, function (datos) {
    datos = $('<div></div>').append(datos);
    ($(datos)).find("#eltoken").html());
    ...
```

See my similar example 
https://jsfiddle.net/011g253w/1/

**Update**

Your code has 2 divs on one level in the body. And `get` returns it as a result of selector `$(*, 'body')` = array of 2 divs.

I found a better way for your case.

```
var eltoken = $(datos).filter("#eltoken");
var result = $(datos).filter("#cuenta_menu_fac");
```

https://jsfiddle.net/011g253w/2/

Comment: You are right. That did the trick. Could you tell me why do we need to add all datos in an empty div? Why does not jquery detect `#eltoken` as his child if it inherits from html and body tags?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Oh, I thought `.get()` got the full data from the page itself, and not only the elements from body. And you are totally right, the second answer also works. Thank you!